# Granting Read access to Replica database (via data guard) but need to restrict the same login in production Database

Tags: oracle, database-administration

We use Data Guard to replicate production Oracle database. We have a need to grant read access to replica DB and at the same time need to restrict that same login gaining read access to production. Since the data guard replicates everything (including user/roles) is there any way we can apply this restriction in the production databases? should I look into to database server inbound port restrictions? any thoughts on this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: btw we use linux server as our Oracle database server

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, this is not really possible. If the user can only log in from a given workstation with a fixed IP, you could limit connections via firewall rules.  Port restrictions can turn into a real mess.